# MUI datePicker Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my react app i'm using mui date picker to pick only the year. so after following every step on their documentation and run the app it throws an error of `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
          <DemoContainer components={["DatePicker"]}>
            <DatePicker
              label={'"year"'}
              openTo="year"
              className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-600 focus:border-teal-800 block w-full p-2.5 h-full"
            />
          </DemoContainer>
        </LocalizationProvider>
```

what is the problem here?